# How to sort the MySql Database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have stored various records in the MySql database "orkut". Now I want to sort that database through a java program. I have connected to the database through the jdbc driver.
Now I want to sort that database in decreasing order of the field "number" of type "int" but don't know the commands. I have "con" reference variable which denotes the connection to the MySql database.

One more thing, there is a field "sr_no" that denotes the serial no. of the record and it is not the primary key.

I want that this field won't change after sorting the database as the serial no. should not change on changing the order of the records.

I want this sorting permanently stored on the same database. I don't want sorted ResultSet.
I want sorted database.

Comment: BTW what you call 'database' is actual called table. Database is set of tables. Do you work with DBase III DBF's before? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't try to sort this through Java--you'll kill yourself trying. SQL has an `order by` clause that does exactly this. Here's the SQL:

```
select
    number,
    sr_no
from
    tbl
order by
    number desc
```

Also note that you cannot have a permanently sorted database. The way that the data is stored does not lend itself to being stored in whatever order you choose. You should *never* count on the order of a database to be the same, unless you use an `order by` in your query.

Answer (score 1):

as eric told you can't have a permanently sorted database. But if you want to execute this query on a large dataset very frequently then you can do indexing supported by various database.

It will speedup your searching and sorting for a particular key.

Comment: Yes, I need to perform this for a very large dataset. It contains millions of records. Can you please explain me how to do this with using the indexing of MySQL. I am using MySQL.
I am upvoting you for this.

Comment: just you need to create index for table and while sorting use
select
    number,
    sr_no
from
    tbl
order by
    number desc